# How to escape unicode characters in a java string without using third party libraries

Tags: java, c#, .net, unicode

I got a .Net project which clients would use and pass in a String. The .Net code calls a java service. Say the string is "\123"

I am not as familiar with .NET as i am with Java.

Looks like C# automatically escapes the unicode \ in the string value and considers that value as "\123" itself.

When the value comes into java it becomes "S" as "\123" is a unicode value and represents "S". This is unacceptable

I can't use apache commons lang StringEscapeUtils due to corporate restrictions on using third party libraries. I don't have a choice here.

So how do I handle all such unicode characters in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply escape the unicode with a double backslash:

`\\123` represents `\123` as a string

Comment: correct. for \ its ok. How about the possibility of handling all such unicode representations?

Comment: @Shiv how does the input into java happen? maybe you could do the escaping before entering the java level. Once the string instance is created it automaticly interprets the unciode parts.

Comment: its a web service call

Comment: u r right. I can't handle this in java.so we went for base 64 encoding in .NET and decoding in java and it solved the issue